# What tag in HTML should I use without special meaning, only to carry meta data?

Tags: javascript, html, metadata

Is there any meainingless HTML tag to carry additional meta data, for example attributes for JavaScript for specified block/area? like:

```
<div class="item">
   <meaninglesselement data-id="123">
   <meaninglesselement data-type="sometype">
   <meaninglesselement data-validate="true">

   ...
</div>
```

I know that I can move `data-*` attributes to `div class="item"` but I want a solution for clean code, even if there will be a lot of parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data applies to the div, the attributes should be on the div. If you want to format your code with one item per line, then you can.

```
<div class="item"
     data-id="123"
     data-type="sometype"
     data-validate="true">
```

There are no elements designed for storing meta data that go in the document body.

Comment: That one looks nice, but when number of possible attributes is huge and each attribute is inserted with PHP/SMARTY (value and even  existance of attribute condition(s) ), then this single tag can have a size of several "screens"

Comment: How is that worse than doing the same thing with multiple elements?

Comment: I will accept this answer, because in fact, we can prepare all esential attribute/value pairs on the backend and just put single `foreach` to write attributes

Comment: Actually there are so called **data blocks**: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#data-block

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho — There *are*, but they aren't the right tool for the job the question is asking about.

Comment: Question is not asking for any specific job, but Javascript is mentioned in the question to handle the data, so a `<script>` would be appropriate instead of `<div>` that is used to structure a presentation. By default the `<script>` is hiding the data (but can be shown by `style="display:block"`).

Comment: @PiotrMüller — The question is asking how to associate data with a block in an HTML document. A div is a generic block element. They are asking how to associate data with that div. They accepted this answer half a decade ago.

Comment: Where do you see it say *HTML document*? It say HTML tag that `<script>` is also.
It say: I know that I can move data-* attributes to div class="item" but I want a solution for clean code. For me it means like *I know div **but** want a solution for clean code* that I understand as pure Javascript. Maybe the answer was accepted because there was no other answers at that time. I have told about the problems of accept-functionality at meta. Often better answer is below.

Comment: I have to say this answer is really a good answer, because it seems as who asked didn't know div can store data and this answer is a minimal answer or it asked for an appropriate tag. Very good answer, so you need not to be protective. Answer is very helpful and to use a so called *data block* as defined by W3C was of no need for them who accepted this answer.

Answer (score 13):

If it is meta data for the whole document that might be useful for visitors or bots, you should use the [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element). You may only use [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) or [registered `name` values](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) (but you could [register](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names) new ones in the wiki).

For meta data that is only needed for your scripts etc., you may use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) on existing elements (e.g. `body`) or you may use the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element):

> The `script` element allows authors to include dynamic script and **data blocks** in their documents. The element **does not represent content for the user**.
>
> […]
>
> When used to include data blocks (as opposed to scripts), the data must be embedded inline, the format of the data must be given using the `type` attribute, the `src` attribute must not be specified, and the contents of the `script` element must conform to the requirements defined for the format used.

You can place this element in the `head` or in the document body where [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (like `span`) can be used, too.

There is an informative example for the use as data block (instead of script):

> ```
>  <script type="text/x-game-map">
>  ........U.........e
>  o............A....e
>  .....A.....AAA....e
>  .A..AAA...AAAAA...e
>  </script>
> ```

So you could use HTML or JSON or whatever format you need.

If you'd want to use HTML, it may (***) look like:

```
<div class="item">
  <script type="text/html">
    <div data-id="123"></div>
    <div data-foo="bar"></div>
    <div>foobar</div>
  </script>
</div>
```

*** ([I'm not sure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19135200/1591669) if it has to be a "full" conforming HTML document or if "snippets", like in my example, are allowed, too)

Comment: Nice solution with script+JSON for more complicated data structures