# Meta Tag in Body

Tags: javascript, html, dom, meta-tags

I'm implementing a system for my customer along the lines of attaching a tracking element to the DOM whenever specific errors are thrown (it simply has to have a certain value in a data-trkError attribute). My first thought was to use a

```
<span data-trkError="BLAH" style="display: none;"></span>
```

But then it occurred to me that this feels intuitively like what the `meta` tag should be usable for. However, this pretty much needs to be appended to a specific div in the DOM, ie within the body. Is this a problem? Is there anything standard-breaking or not-best-practises about a meta tag in the body tree?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<meta>`-tag is part of the [4.2 Document metadata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#document-metadata). Therefor it can only appear in the `<head>`-section of a document. Your solution using a `<span>` or a `<div>` or even a list for multiple errors is just fine for your purpose.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to clinch it. OK, thanks for the handy documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that `meta` would fit better than an empty `span`. However (even *if* you could use them in `body`), note that you can’t just use custom `meta` keywords. In HTML5, only [defined/registered values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) are valid.

But you can have `meta` elements in `body`, if they are used for Microdata or RDFa. For example, RDFa [extends](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax) HTML5:

> If the `@property` RDFa attribute is present on the `link` or `meta` elements, they MUST be viewed as conforming if used in the `body` of the document. More specifically, when `link` or `meta` elements contain the RDFa `@property` attribute and are used in the `body` of an HTML5 document, they MUST be considered flow content.

So you could create (or reuse an existing) vocabulary for your metadata. But, depending on your use case, this might be overkill.

As an alternative to `span` I’d [use the `script` element as data block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428316/1591669):

> The `script` element allows authors to include dynamic script and **data blocks** in their documents. The element does not represent content for the user.

For example:

```
<script type="text/plain"> <!-- or whichever MIME type suits your need -->
  <!-- your data -->
  <!-- you could of course use data-* attributs on this script element, too -->
</script>
```

Comment: The use of a `script` tag's interesting - never thought of using a non-`text/javascript` tag!