# text/html in script element: Does it need to be a conformant document?

Tags: html

In HTML5, the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can be used for data blocks:

> The `script` element allows authors to include dynamic script and **data blocks** in their documents.

The [`type` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) gives the MIME type of the content.

If `text/html` is used, does the `script` element have to contain a *full* HTML document? Or are snippets (like in the following example) allowed, too?

```
<script type="text/html">
  <div>Foobar.</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Ineteresting... And what happens if you run this through the W3C HTML validator?

Comment: The spec only says, _“[…] and the contents of the script element must conform to the requirements defined for the format used.”_ – but I doubt it would make much sense to deliver a whole HTML document here. And any HTML in there will most likely be problematic in older browsers, so I think I’d rather use text/plain as format, encode any HTML special characters inside it properly, and then parse it afterwards (which in its simplest way could just mean appeding the text somewhere via innerHTML).

Comment: @ChrisHardie: It’s valid, but the W3C validator doesn’t inspect the content of `script` elements at all (apart from disallowed characters), in the same way that it doesn’t validate the JavaScript contained in `script` elements. So I can add `<div>Foobar</p>`, too, and it doesn’t give me an error.

Comment: Well, if you do use a snipped, you are in good company: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/