# Content-Type for Email Markup Actions

Tags: email, mime-types, content-type, schema.org, google-schemas

I've been looking at email [Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/declaring-actions) (which apparently are in a process of being standardized), and considering implementing these for an application of mine.

However, the entire documentation seems to be missing the mime-type to define for the message part that includes this json-ld metadata. For example, gpg signatures are marked as

```
Content-Type: application/pgp-signature; name="signature.asc"
```

What Content-Type does this part (eg: [this content](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/declaring-actions#go-to_actions)) need to be included as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include it in the email’s HTML (`text/html`).

Google (i.e., Gmail and Inbox by Gmail) [supports](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started) JSON-LD and Microdata:

- The JSON-LD will be included in a `script` element (used [as data block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428316/1591669)).
- The Microdata attributes (like `itemscope` and `itemprop`) will be added directly to the (existing) HTML elements.

So, if your email would contain this HTML

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Foobar</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

you could add JSON-LD to it like this

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "Foobar"
    }
    </script>
    <p>Hello!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and Microdata like this

```html
<html>
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <p itemprop="name">Foobar</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I **need** to use html email in order to include this meta data? It's not a separate mime part?

Comment: @Hugo: Yes, according to Google’s documentation, they only support the Schema.org annotations if used in HTML. I guess (didn’t test it) you could send both, `text/plain` and `text/html`, in `multipart/alternative` and [place the `text/plain` version last](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_email#Multi-part_formats) (if you want clients to prefer the plain text version).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd much rather avoid adding any text/html parts to my emails. Hopefully this will be improved at some point, and these actions will become a separate mime-part.

Comment: @Hugo You could use it as a separate mime type but the issue is that some clients(i.e. gmail) don't recognise it. I think the best way to handle this would be to send both both html (with the json-ld embedded) and a separate json-ld mime so that we can 'force' the clients to consider supporting it. I would like a separate mime too so that I can send only the json-ld and perhaps the 'text/plain' version as fallback but we are really at the mercy of the major email clients(i.e. ios email, gmail, yahoo, outlook, mozilla).