# Is there any way to Introduce Menus Structure By Microdata schema.org?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

Is there any way to Introduce Menus Structure By Microdata schema.org

```
Parent1 | Parent2 | Parent3
______________________________
Sub 1-1 | Sub-2-1 | Sub3-1
______________________________
Sub 1-2 | Sub-2-2 | Sub3-2
______________________________
Sub 1-3 | Sub-2-3 | Sub3-3
```

AND the CODE:

```
<div>
 <ul>
    <li>
       <span>Paent1</span><div><ul><li>sub1-1</li><li>sub1-2</li><li>sub1-3</li></ul>
    </li>

    <li>
       <span>Paent2...</ul>
    </li>

    <li>
       <span>Paent3....</ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

I tried sth like this:

```
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Main menu" />

     <ul>
        <li itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
           <span itemprop="name">Paent1</span><div><ul><li>sub1-1</li><li>sub1-2</li><li>sub1-3</li></ul>
        </li>

        <li itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
           <span itemprop="name">Paent2...</ul>
        </li>

        <li itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
           <span itemprop="url">Paent3....</ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren’t using any properties to relate the nested items to their parent. See the second part of [my answer on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59369/17633) for a short example of this problem.

I don’t think that Schema.org provides appropriate types and properties for this case. Also, [`SiteNavigationElement` is probably (not definitely) meant for the whole navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133880/1591669), not for its single links.

The closest I can think of would be:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">

  <ul itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">

    <li itemprop="itemListElement">…</li>

    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">…
      <ul>
       <li itemprop="itemListElement">…</li>
       <li itemprop="itemListElement">…</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li itemprop="itemListElement">…</li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

This is a `SiteNavigationElement` whose subject matter consists of an `ItemList`, and some of this list’s entries consist of `ItemList` again. But this is kind of a misuse, especially as [the `itemListElement` property expects *Text*](http://schema.org/itemListElement), not other `ItemList` items.

Also there is the problem that the `itemListElement` whose value is another `ItemList` can’t have an own value. One could overcome this by using:

```html
<!-- … -->
<li itemprop="itemListElement">AAA
  <ul itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement">BBB</li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement">CCC</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<!-- … -->
```

But here the problem is: the `itemListElement` value is not "AAA" but "AAA BBB CCC".

So maybe:

```html
<!-- … -->
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">AAA
  <meta itemprop="name" content="AAA" />
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement">BBB</li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement">CCC</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<!-- … -->
```

This would give the correct structure, but, well … it’s ugly, isn’t it? Having to duplicate the name of the 'AAA' entry.

---

Why do you want to mark this up with Microdata in the first place? Do you expect consumers (like search engines) to pick this up? Couldn’t they simply parse the HTML, that already conveys the structure thanks to the use of `li` and nested `ul` elements? Depending on your needs, you could use a ["local" Microdata vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19134534/1591669).