# In Django, how to use settings.py constant from a static file?

Tags: python, django, file, static, settings

I have a static file that I use in my template.

I need to hide some information in this file code but I normally use **settings.py** constants to do that.

How can I instance a **settings.py** constant in a static file?

I tried `{{CONSTANT}}` but iit doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Static files are not processed in any way, they are not templates, and you can't interpolate values into them. The *static* in the name means just that; variable interpolation would make them dynamic instead.

Create a new view that serves the same response, using a template.

Alternatively, consider putting the constant [into your HTML you already generate with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533764/best-practice-for-meta-data-in-a-html-document) and have Javascript pull it out on the client side. That way your static resources can remain static, including JavaScript code.