# Do we have a html tag/meta tag that doesn't functionality/UI/Performance/Security, still made available in view source?

Tags: html

Our DevOps Engineer is preparing a deployment script to deploy the new Angular code to production. We need to ensure whether the new code changes are indeed reflected in production. He needs to make small changes in the application source code and ensure it gets reflected in the target environment through the deployment script. He'd likely change hello1, hello2, hello3 to test his script. Is there a Html tag/meta-tag where we can set arbitary value that doesn't affect the app's behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a plain old `<span style="display:none;">hello1</span>` here.

A `<span>` carries no semantic and `display: none;` hides it from view.
Otherwise, You could use an `<!-- HTML comment -->`.

Comment: Great. How about meta tags like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/10533764/959939?