# Sending html file and other data as response for an express route

Tags: javascript, html, json, express

Is there a way to send an html file and other JSON or other type of data simultaneously, but without using a template engine such as EJS or so? It seems like this method is pretty outdated due to the small quantity of new information about it. Below is an example where I'm sending an html file as response to the client and let's say I want to send some JSON data along with it which I will manipulate in the client side of the application.

```
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../pages/main-page.html");
  res.sendFile(filePath);
});
```

I tried to find another way to do this without template engines and I couldn't find something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533764/best-practice-for-meta-data-in-a-html-document This question isn't a duplicate, but the answer may be helpful. Using something like a customized `<meta data-whatever=...` tag seems like a reasonable way to include some additional custom data into your html response. However, this would require parsing and injecting into the html document (pretty easy to do in node with something like cheerio). Otherwise you could use a custom header if the data is small.